# Gmail and Outlook pages rendered as source html in Chrome and Edge

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-outlook, gmail, microsoft-edge

I am having this weird problem with both Chrome and Edge browsers: The Gmail (mail.google.com) and Outlook (outlook.live.com) pages are rendered as html source files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html dir=ltr xmlns=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml translate=no> 
<head> <meta charset=utf-8> <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv=pragma content=no-cache> <meta name=viewport content="width=
device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=0"><meta name=google value=notranslate> 
<meta name=format-detection content="telephone=no"><meta name=scriptVer content=
.
.
.
```

But Firefox displays those two pages correctly. What in the world is going on here?

I noticed the problem disappeared when using the Incognito window, so I cleared all cookies, data and browsing history and that fixed the problem.....temporarily. After a while (less than an hour), when switching from reading a message back to the inbox, boom! pure raw html again.

Answer (score -1):

Considering that the issue is related to the Gmail (mail.google.com) and Outlook (outlook.live.com) pages, and doesn't occur in Firefox, so i'm afraid that the issue is more related to Edge itself. It's suggested that you could uninstall Microsoft Edge and install the latest Edge to check if there're any differences.

Comment: The OP mentions both Chrome and Edge. That suggests a common problem with Chromium based browsers and the user's profile/extensions, etc.